# How to extract attachments from a Notes app on OS X?

Tags: lotus-notes

I've got a Notes app which is accessed from Windows and OS X clients. I have a function which extracts an attachment from a doc. It works fine in Windows but is throwing this error: "Error in loading DLL". I'm using EmbeddedObject.ExtractFile but the documentation says "Note: Embedded objects and object links are not supported for OS/2, UNIX, and the Macintosh. File attachments are." I'm not quite sure what that means. Anyone know how to extract attachments on OS X?

thanks
clem

Comment: ExtractFile *should* work. The note you're seeing is referring to OLE embeds (where you interact with the foreign content directly on the Notes document rather than in a separate application). If the NotesEmbeddedObject is actually an embedded object (a live Excel sheet or something similar) rather than an attachment, you can't really get at it cleanly except in Windows.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Found the problem.  I found some code online which allowed you to grab the temp folder. That's where I was going to dump the files into.  After some digging, I found that the library declaration was wrong.  It was this:

      'Declare Function mac_OSGetSystemTempDirectory Lib "NotesLib" Alias "OSGetSystemTempDirectory" ( ByVal S As String) As Integer
Declare Function mac_OSGetSystemTempDirectory Lib "libnotes.dylib" Alias "OSGetSystemTempDirectory" ( ByVal S As String) As Integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem -- it turned out to be 2 issues:

1) I found some code online which allowed you to grab the temp folder. That's where I was going to dump the files into.  After some digging, I found that the library declaration was wrong.  It was this:

```
  Declare Function mac_OSGetSystemTempDirectory Lib "NotesLib" Alias "OSGetSystemTempDirectory" ( ByVal S As String) As Integer
```

But should have been this:

```
 Declare Function mac_OSGetSystemTempDirectory Lib "libnotes.dylib" Alias "OSGetSystemTempDirectory" ( ByVal S As String) As Integer
```

2) When I issued the NotesEmbeddedObject.ExtractFile, I used only the folder in the argument instead of the folder-name + file-name.

Thanks for the response -- it forced myself to double-check everything.

Clem